# Show email next to name in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Does anyone know a way to display the sender's email next to the name?

See below mockup:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

From [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en#zippy=%2Ci-see-an-email-address-next-to-the-senders-name):

> You'll see the sender's email address next to their name if it's someone you haven't emailed in the past.
>
> If you add this sender to your address book or reply to one of their emails, you won't see their email address next to their name on future messages.

For more details see - [Extra info next to sender’s name](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182).

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really tell me how to tweak this.

Comment: You cannot display it manually.